# Pixelated stencil

Tags: texturing, texture-painting

Question: why is my 8k texture so pixelated when I use it as a stencil? I can't draw if I can't see what I'm drawing D: [image]

Comment: What's the resolution of the image on which you stencil? How much texture space have you given the pixelated area? (UV map)

Comment: 8k source on 8k canvas. I separated the rgb channels of combined displacement map in separate picrtures and the other ones work fine, only this one is weird... Don't know wym by texture space? O_o